# JavaScript Code for Accordion Menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

(Finally solved) When every body tells you that the code is good and even demonstrates it, and yet it doesn't work AT YOUR PLACE, than you're probably making a trivial mistake. Mine was the order in which jQuery, menumaker and finally my local script should have been invoked (it's the order above), and NOT in any other order.

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/01_MainMenu.js"></script>
```

The error was pointed out by the Google Chrome Debugger, which I didn't use until now, but certainly will use from now on.

(Update) Thanks for all your answers. The reference to jQuery was present to a local copy of jQuery: 
`<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>`
I also tried the script with the link gavgrif suggested, but unfortunately, it is still not working.

But I get the following error in the Mozilla Firefox Debugger:

**message: jQuery is not defined.**

[image: Firefox Debugger error message]

The error message refers to the last line (26) in the script, the one that contains the "(jQuery)".

(Original post)

I received this script from CSS MenuMaker, which is supposed to make an accordion menu with sub menus expand / contract. But I don't understand the (jQuery) bit at the end, and why the whole script stands between round parentheses. I AM a JavaScript novice.

Obviously, the script is not working.

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#main_menu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
    $('#main_menu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
    $('#main_menu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
      $('#main_menu li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
      var checkElement = $(this).next();
      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
      }
      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#main_menu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      }
      if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;   
      }     
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
   <div id="main_menu">
   <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="../Main.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/04_Taxonomy.php">Taxonomy</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/01_PlantList.php">Virtual Herbarium</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/03_PlantData.php">Data Repository</a></li>
      <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Sources</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/072_Surse_Books.php">Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/073_Surse_Journals.php">Journals</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Habitats</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Endangered species</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Papers</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

The corresponding CSS is quite long. If it is needed, I'll post it, but personally I don't think so.

Comment: The bit at the end is related to the parentheses wrapping the code, it's an Inline Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). Used in this case stop stop any external code interfering with the `$` variable.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed unusual to me. I have never seen it before.

Comment: Do you want to know why it isn't working, or what `(function () {...}())` is. those are two very different and unrelated questions. One is a duplicate, the other can't be answered unless you provide more information.

Comment: Actually, both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the script not working - I just copied your code into this code snippet to answer it and it works - clicking the "sources" link opens and closes the sub menu as expected. If it is not working for you then I suspect you have not included the jquery library in the head of the document.

Try adding

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

into the head and see if it works. And for the rest of the forum - yes this should be a comment - but I wanted to demonstrate through the snippet that the code works with the addition of the snippet :)

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#main_menu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
    $('#main_menu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
    $('#main_menu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
      $('#main_menu li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
      var checkElement = $(this).next();
      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
      }
      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#main_menu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      }
      if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;   
      }     
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="main_menu">
   <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="../Main.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/04_Taxonomy.php">Taxonomy</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/01_PlantList.php">Virtual Herbarium</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pages/03_PlantData.php">Data Repository</a></li>
      <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Sources</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/072_Surse_Books.php">Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/073_Surse_Journals.php">Journals</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Habitats</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Endangered species</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Papers</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I used a local copy of jquery, which was included:

Comment: The above comment is incomplete. I would have liked to be able to delete it, but the functionality of this website doesn't allow me to. I wrote what i wanted to write in my main post, section (Update).

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea is to 'protect' this script if any other script uses the '$' for anything else in your code. So this is a totally valid script.

The 'regular' jQuery object to be used is 'jQuery'. But '$' can be used as a shortcut.
Unfortunately, some other frameworks uses '$' as well. If you were to use such frameworks, this script could not work anymore.

So :

```
(function($){

//Code using '$'

})(jQuery)
```

Prevent that. And this is how (it is quite simple).
It declares an anonymous function taking a parameter. This parameter is called $ (it could be called *param1* or something).
then, it just calls the function with the variable 'jQuery', which is the jQuery object (which is defined globally).

This would be similar:

```
function foo(param1){
  param1('#main_menu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
  param1('#main_menu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
  //...etc...
}

foo(jQuery);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand why the jQuery has to be there.